# Handling the inverse of a complex condition

Tags: vb.net, while-loop, conditional-statements

I have a fairly complex condition that actually combines a few nested conditions in my code:

```
Sub RunWorkload()
    If iisSvr1rstdone = True And (iisSvr2rstdone = True Or utilnamespace.iisSvr2 = "") And (rptSvrrstdone = True Or utilnamespace.rptSvr = "") And (Workload.chkCache.Checked = False Or sqlSvrrstdone = True) Then
        Workload.txtStatus.Text = "Running Workload..."
        <more things happen>
    End If
End Sub
```

My problem is that as the code is written right now, it only fires the evaluation once, which simply doesn't work. Each of those `done` variables is a boolean that is populated as part of an "I'm done!" event. So if it's not populated currently it should re-evaluate periodically.

That brings me to the question I have now: I'm considering replacing the `If` with a `While`, but that would involve writing the inverse of that condition, so something like:

```
While iisSvr1rstdone = False And (iisSvrrstdone = False or utilnamespace.iisSvr IsNot Nothing) And (rptSvrrstdone = False or utilnamespace.rptSvr IsNot Nothing) And (Workload.chkCache.Checked = True or sqlSvrrstdone = True)
```

Which I could loop through until it evaluates as `True`. My problem with this is that it just seems... overly complex, and I'm afraid I'm missing something that would simplify it. Another idea I had was to store the results of the If statement as a separate function, so that I could just have the While statement constantly run the function until it evaluates as true.

Am I missing anything that would make this concept click?

Comment: When you call `RunWorkload`, do you want it to wait until all the conditions are met, then <make things happen>? Or call `RunWorkload` and only <make things happen> if the conditions are met?

Comment: Also, removing the `= True` and `= False` from your Boolean expressions will make it appear less complex.

Comment: It needs to wait until all conditions are satisfied. The booleans all default to False (I declare them as False and then have events switch them to True).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to "inverse" a boolean statement is to use

```
If Not (a=b) Then
```

instead of

```
If a=b Then
```

I noticed that the very last part in your code

```
(Workload.chkCache.Checked = False Or sqlSvrrstdone = sqlSvrrstdone = True)
```

does not make sense, since the part after the Or would be always true, so the whole thing would always be True, which then, since it is And connected to the rest would make the whole thing unnecessary. Maybe it is a bug in your code or you can just delete the whole thing.
To reverse the statements by hand you would replace all the `= True` with `= False` and the `Or` with `And` and vice versa. So it would be

```
If iisSvr1rstdone = False Or _
   (iisSvr2rstdone = False And utilnamespace.iisSvr2 <> "") Or _
   (rptSvrrstdone = False And utilnamespace.rptSvr <> "") Then
```

This should do the inverse of your if statement, if I didn't mess it up. The unnecessary part I mentioned before is deleted from this.

Using a separate function for this type of code is always a good idea because it makes the code much more readable.

Comment: Ah yeah that was a typo. I edited my code. You're right, too. That last bit is unnecessary code.

Answer (score 1):

I would make a method which waits while the conditions are not met. I broke them up into separate chunks for better readability. The Async / Await allows the UI thread to continue processing other events, or you can just block it by calling `waitForServersReady` directly.

```
Private iisSvr1rstdone, iisSvr2rstdone, rptSvrrstdone, sqlSvrrstdone, WorkloadchkCacheChecked As Boolean
Private utilnamespaceiisSvr2, utilnamespacerptSvr, WorkloadtxtStatusText As String

Private Sub waitForServersReady()
    While Not iisSvr1rstdone
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1)
    End While
    While Not (iisSvr2rstdone Or utilnamespaceiisSvr2 = "")
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1)
    End While
    While Not (rptSvrrstdone Or utilnamespacerptSvr = "")
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1)
    End While
    While Not (WorkloadchkCacheChecked Or sqlSvrrstdone)
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1)
    End While
End Sub

Async Sub RunWorkload()
    Await Task.Factory.StartNew(AddressOf waitForServersReady)
    ' you can also just waitForServersReady()
    WorkloadtxtStatusText = "Running Workload..."
End Sub
```

Comment: Ah, I see. The benefit of this is that my UI thread could keep on doing other things while those tasks finish up. Clever, I've never used Await or Async processing like that (the previous iteration of this was just a console app so it was a bit simpler). Thanks!

Comment: @SeanLong I would remove `= True` since the statement `True = True` is redundant while `True` does the job.

Comment: Another possibility is to use a SELECT CASE TRUE and in each CASE test a condition.